# Table / tabular enviroment doesn't build the pdf

Tags: tables, pdftex, tabularx, multicolumn, input

i was trying to create a table of with 3 columns  `\begin{tabular}` but once i had completed it, Latex can't manage to build the .pdf. I've made already some tables that had no problem with it, and i can't seem to get what is not working. The code is

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
{
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{Marginal effects in Probit model (1) and Logit model(2) Conditioned to Sample mean \label{marg2}}
\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{c}}
\toprule
                        &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}}\\
\midrule
           &                         &                  \\
eta         &      0.087 \sym{***}&      0.083\sym{***}\\
            &     (.001)         &     (.0012)         \\
\addlinespace
eta\_sq      &    -0.001\sym{***} &   -0.000989\sym{***}\\
            &    (.000)          &    (.000)         \\
\hline\hline
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize mean(eta)=51.44, mean(eta\_sq)=30127.38 }\\
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
```

In my code i use  `\input{file_name.tex}` to import it, but it makes no difference wheter to call the file or write the table enviroment in the main tex file.

I used it for a similar output which gives me as a result this table

[image: Table]

which i'm totally satisfied with it. But the previous code won't load a table and keeps building the .pdf without stopping. I even let it build for half an hour without a result.
Thanks for the attention!

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: I would put your coefficients in math mode. Your minus signs would then look right.

Comment: Also note that writing `.000` is not legal in the SI. Writing `0.000` is.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `}` to much at the second `\multicolumn` command. Remove it (and all other not needed groups), e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \def\sym#1{\ensuremath{^{#1}}}%
  \caption{Marginal effects in Probit model (1) and Logit model(2) Conditioned to Sample mean \label{marg2}}
  \begin{tabular}{l*{2}{c}}
    \toprule
                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)} \\
    \midrule
                &                         &                  \\
    eta         &      0.087 \sym{***}    &      0.083\sym{***}\\
                &     (.001)              &     (.0012)         \\
    \addlinespace
    eta\_sq     &    -0.001\sym{***}      &   -0.000989\sym{***}\\
                &    (.000)               &    (.000)         \\
    \bottomrule
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize mean(eta)=51.44, mean(eta\_sq)=30127.38 }\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW: The `\multicolumn` commands make not sense in this example, because the columns are already specified to be of type `c`.

Note: `[h]` does not mean "here and nowhere else" but "here if possible". LaTeX automatically adds `t` if needed. I would suggest to add at least `p` always to avoid floating to the end of the document (or chapter with `book` or `report`).

Comment: Since the Op does not seem to be a macho TeX programmer (in Lamport's parlance), I would rather say `\newcommand{\sym}[1]{\ensuremath{^{#1}}}`

Comment: @Denis Inside the document preamble absolutely. Inside a local environment … depends on whether it should be defined without any respect to already existing definitions of `\sym` or not. BTW: In real live I would also suggest to use `siunitx` for number columns. However, I did not want to change everything. Maybe I even should have changed only the real mistake. But because I've already changed this command and removed the not needed extra group, I've posted, what I've really tested and was to lazy to revert all not needed changes.

Comment: Agreed. Also `siunitx` is very welcomed.